# Jquery toggle slide bugs

Tags: jquery, html, css

Sorry for asking it again, but I still don't have an answer on my old question...
I have to fix this today, I hope you guys can help me.

I have a jquery hover.

It's a div in a div, the div with the hover is called .flip and the div which expands is called .panel.

The hover bugs, when I go over .flip expands .panel. But panel is in the div .flip so the hovering flip will be as big as .flip + the size of .panel. And .flip has to be as width as .panel what i don't want..

I know that its possible to let .panel out of .flip but it has to stay in there. Else all the .panel's will expand when i hover over one of the 5 .flip's. So I have to use $this.

The second problem is, that when i go 2, 3, 4 or more times over the .flip, .panel will expand 2, 3, 4 or more times and that looks laggy.

Can you help me? I know nothing about jquery, so I even don't know where to search for.

Here is the link: http://staging.skyberate.nl/shared-hosting/magento-hosting/referenties/

Code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".flip").hover(function(){
         $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("slow"); 
    });
}); 
</script>
```

css:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.flip{
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color:white;
     width:490px;
    margin-left: 43px;
    color:#1667b2;
    text-align:center;
    border-top; 2px #1667b2 solid
    display:block;
}

.panel
{
    width:490px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#1667b2;
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    display:none;
    padding:5px;
}

#meerreferenties {
    width:auto;
    float:left;
}

</style>
```

html:

```
<div class="flip">Klik hier voor meer informatie.
    <div class="panel">Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
        Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
        Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
        Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
        Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
        Hier komt de informatie te staan over de hosting van Chocstar.
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bTL5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just as easy as changing your jQuery from:

```
$(".flip").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("slow"); 
});
```

to:

```
$(".flip").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".panel").stop().slideToggle("slow"); 
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4bTL5/15/)

**Explanation:**

This basically just stops the current jQuery animation `.slideToggle`. It doesn't complete the animation (going to the bottom), but goes back immediately, as it should, cause it's a `slideToggle` animation on a `hover` function.

**Extra help:**

As I helped you yesterday and I know what you kind of want, I fixed your css, I think it isn't how you wanted it to be.

[JSFiddle with blueline ^^](http://jsfiddle.net/4bTL5/16/)

Comment: Thank you all guys, but this one worked. There are more people who said me this, but then with "true,true" between .stop() Can you look at my site? sometimes when i go over "meer informatie" it wont slidedown for 100% I dont know why.. link: http://staging.skyberate.nl/shared-hosting/magento-hosting/referenties/

Comment: Yeah, i hadn't seen your edit with the css fix. Thank you very much, that looks pretty pretty cool! But do you know why the element sometimes won't slide down?

Comment: That's basically because of a bug in jQuery, because you're using `hover` and `slideToggle`. Try this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/4bTL5/17/

Comment: What I basically did is create a 'hover' effect by using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: You could also minimize this script to 1 function by binding the 2 elements to the same function: http://jsfiddle.net/4bTL5/19/

Comment: Thanks, i used your first one, with mouse enter and leave in 2 different functions, then i do understand it more;p Aannnddd, there is one little very big problem. It doesn't work on google chrome xD

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's your HTML being screwed up, you have `<div class="flip">Meer informatie</p>`, change that to `<div class="flip"><p>Meer informatie</p>` or `<div class="flip">Meer informatie`

Comment: Oh okay, on my chrome it doesn't but if you say it:P Is there a way to fix that little bug that it wont expand sometimes?

Comment: Isn't it fixed already? I changed the `hover` function to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to fix it. I think it's currently not working cause of invalid HTML </p> tags. Read my last comment.

Comment: I put all the text between <p> tags, but still the bug:P

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem you can use `position:absolute` for `child div` so `parent div` will not take a `height` of a `absolute div`, and for second problem you can use `stop()` before `slideToggle`.
Check this...http://jsfiddle.net/4bTL5/14/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I use that, the other elements wont slide down and the page wont be longer when i toggle on hover..